# Returning a string from a for loop

Tags: java, string

I'm working on a project for my java programming 1 class where you're supposed to take a string and change upper case to lower and lower to upper for each letter in the string. Here is my code so far, no matter what I try I can't get the program to return my final string for output.

```
import java.util.*;

public class LowerUpper {
    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        Scanner letters = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter 3 letters:");
        String input = letters.next();
        int length = input.length();

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
            if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) {
                Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
            else if (Character.isLowerCase(input.charAt(i))) {
                Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i));
                break;
            }
            return input.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for help! I'm sure it's just a simple solution that I'm missing.

Comment: Strings are immutable, in the code you don't change the string, but just get upper/lower copies of it characters. Try to use `String.toUpperCase()` and  `String.toLowerCase()` methods, like "abcd".toUpperCase();

Answer (score 2):

First, it's `main` (not `Main`). Second, you forgot to create a second method (that returns `String`), you can't return a `String` from a `void` method (like `main`). Once you've got a method, you'll need to call it. But, let's start with the method. You need to store the characters as you generate them. In Java 8+, you might do

```
public static String swapCase(String input) {
    return input.codePoints()
            .map(ch -> Character.isUpperCase(ch) ?
                       Character.toLowerCase(ch) : 
                       Character.toUpperCase(ch))
            .collect(StringBuilder::new, 
                       StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, 
                       StringBuilder::append).toString();
}
```

**or** like,

```
public static String swapCase(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
    for (char ch : chars) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) {
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        } else {
            sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(ch));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

**or** like,

```
public static String swapCase(String input) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    input.chars().forEachOrdered(ch -> {
        sb.append(Character.isUpperCase(ch) ? 
                Character.toLowerCase(ch) :
                Character.toUpperCase(ch));
    });
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then to call it,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner letters = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter 3 letters:");
    String input = letters.next();
    System.out.printf("Original: %s, Swapped: %s%n", input, swapCase(input));
}
```

Comment: plus one for noticing the `main`

Comment: If you're going to use streams and lambdas, why not just map the input instead of mutating a StringBuilder? Side effects are evil, after all :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a `StringBuilder` to keep your converted chars in.

Also you do not want to `break` else you will only convert the first char

try something like

```
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder ();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
  if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) {
    buf.append (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
    // break;
  }
  else  {
    buf.append (Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
    // break;
  }
 }

return buf.toString ();
```

**edit**

test solution

```
    String input = "this iS my test";
    int length = input.length();

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder ();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        if (Character.isUpperCase(input.charAt(i))) {
            buf.append (Character.toLowerCase(input.charAt(i)));
            // break;
        }
        else  {
            buf.append (Character.toUpperCase(input.charAt(i)));
            // break;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(buf.toString ());
```

**output**

> THIS Is MY TEST